# Quicker way to move cursor to end of document (Word userform VBA huge performance problem)

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform, sendkeys, slowdown

I have a Word template with contains two userforms.
When closing the forms (.Hide), first text from the form is inserted into bookmarks and the bookmarks' color is changed if needed; then the cursor should be moved to the end of the document. However, this simple step performs extremely slow !

```
Private Sub Fertig_Click()     ''''' code in userform

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
QL(19) = TextBox4.Text: QL(20) = "CHF": QL(21) = "K"
QL(22) = TextBox1.Text: QL(23) = TextBox2.Text: QL(24) = TextBox3.Text
' leere QL-Felder werden nicht geändert
Call PasteIntoBookmark("Name", TextBox1.Text)
Call PasteIntoBookmark("Strasse", TextBox2.Text)
Call PasteIntoBookmark("Ort", TextBox3.Text)
Call PasteIntoBookmark("Betrag", TextBox4.Text)
Call PasteIntoBookmark("Referenz", TextBox5.Text)
'————————————————
Dim StartTime
StartTime = Timer
Debug.Print Right(Format(Timer - StartTime, "#0.00"), 5) & " [timer start]"
'————————————————  output:  0.00
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
Debug.Print Right(Format(Timer - StartTime, "#0.00"), 5) & " seconds !!!"
'————————————————  output:  6.10 seconds !!!
'StartTime = Timer
' who knows any quicker command to reach the document's end ?
'Debug.Print Right(Format(Timer - StartTime, "#0.00"), 5) & " seconds"
'————————————————
Call Farbe("Datum", True)
If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 0 Or Len(TextBox2.Text) = 0 Or Len(TextBox3.Text) = 0 Then
    Call Farbe("Feld_1", False)
    Call Farbe("Feld_4", False)
Else
    Call Farbe("Feld_1", True)
    Call Farbe("Feld_4", True)
End If

' …………

End Sub
```

==== The following code is located in a module of the .dotm template:

```
Sub Farbe(ByVal Feld As String, ByVal Sichtbar As Boolean)
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=Feld
If Sichtbar = True Then
    Selection.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic   ' schwarz
Else
    Selection.Font.Color = -603914241         ' weiss
End If
End Sub
```

As can be seen, the usual command
**Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove**
needs ***more than 6 seconds*** on my quite fast personal computer (Systemscore 8.1) ! *Omitting the ,Extend:=wdMove makes no difference at all*.
Note that the whole rest of the userform code including numerous calls to the Farbe() sub terminates in much less than 1 second (thanks multitasking), the sub then waits only on .Endkey to finish.

Hence I need a much quicker vba code to position the cursor at the end of the Word document from the userform… Thanks in advance for good suggestions.
Of course, pushing <CTRL><END> keys interactively in the document itself is as usual extremely fast. The bug is in the userform's vba code execution.

Comment: Untested - Try `ThisDocument.Range(ThisDocument.Range.End).Select`. Note: You should avoid relying on selection and instead work on the `Range` object directly

Comment: @Raymond Wu The document range, needs two parameters. I think, your (good) suggested solution should be adapted in: `ThisDocument.Range(ThisDocument.Range.End - 1, ThisDocument.Range.End).Select`... And being followed by `Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd`, to clear selection. Which may allow that the first parameter to be (almost) anything.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you, however the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.range) suggested both parameters are optional and thus providing just the starting position should be sufficient since OP wants the end of document. Nevertheless because it's untested on my end, OP can try both suggestions!

Comment: @Raymond Wu I very seldom use WBA Word. I tried your suggestion and received an error: (`Value out of range`). Then I searched for the range definition, but after that I could do it using `ThisDocument.Range(ThisDocument.Range.End - 1).Select`. `Selection.Collapse` will clear selection, anyhow. Like I tried suggesting, your credit must go to you. I never used/needed it...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you! I suspected it might need -1 due to the paragraph marker. OP Please try it and see if it's faster.

Comment: @Raymond Wu Let him try it. I have a small document, just for testing and it may be irrelevant for my case...

Comment: For a collapsed selection you need `ThisDocument.Range(ThisDocument.Range.End - 1, ThisDocument.Range.End - 1).Select`

Comment: Oooh ! Sorry, this code doesn't work correctly either!!!
I tested the 2 alternatives one after the other - the first one needs 6", the second only 0.02". BUT this does NOT depend on the order of the two commands. When .Endkey is first it is slow, when second fast; end the same is true with .Range.End: first slow, second fast !
When I use only one of the two, both alternatives are slow !
And when I use twice the same command, the first time it is slow, the second time fast…
By the way, GoToBookmark also needs 6 seconds !

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is no answer because **this is clearly a BUG !**
I tried the following 3 command lines in different orders:

```
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
ThisDocument.Range(ThisDocument.Range.End - 1, ThisDocument.Range.End - 1).Select
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToField, Name:="Date"
' "Date" is a bookmark, but What:=wdGoToBookmark leads to an error (Office 2019 ×64)
```

In all cases the first of the 3 command lines requires 6 seconds, the further only 0.02 seconds - independently of which of these command lines is executed first and which later !

The bookmark trial was done as an alternative because the end of the document is in a frame, not where the edits do finish … *By the way, the cursor's position and the selection width have no effect.*

Hence I will just avoid repositioning the cursor/selection.

Comment: You did NOT follow the directions from Raymond Wu.

Comment: That is ***not a bug***. You evidently have the view mode for your document set to Print Layout. For Word to display the end of the document it first has to load all content, determine the capabilities of the currently assigned print driver, fully paginate the document, and build a visual representation of what the document may look like when printed. that will take longer if the document contains graphics. If performance is more important to you set the view mode to Normal.

Comment: Sorry you are wrong ! My code also works with bookmarks and this fails (error 6124) when I leave the print layout. But the problem is deeper: when I simplify my whole userform procedure to one single line

     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item(BookmarkName).Select

this also takes full 6 seconds to execute though successful (the selected bookmark can e.g. be formatted). 
Obviously the userform needs this time to find the function; once loaded, selecting many other bookmarks can be repeated very quickly (<0.02 s). But the first call is extremely slow and this is OBVIOUSLY A BUG.

Comment: All of the operations in the code in your question, except for moving the cursor to the end of the document for whatever reason, can be accomplished without selecting anything. But what you have described is not a bug. It is merely a consequence of the document content being loaded. That is why subsequent operations are completed more quickly.

Comment: Please consider that my document is very small: just one page (143 KB); in addition, it is already loaded and visible on screen when the macro runs. Maybe .GoTo / Selection. commands load it again separately in memory, but I don't see why this would be necessary.